# getRange from one file to another for newdatavalidation

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function test() {
  var  id = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('FILEID')
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1');
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getRange('A1:A10');
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range, true).build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

I need to get a range from one spreadsheet file to set in another file as Datavalidation but it gives an error: argument "=sheet!A1:A10" not valid. I think .getrange don't run from one file to another file. Can you help me, please? tks.

Comment: Because openID + getrange , it always gets  value from sheet1  (from FILEID).

Comment: Right! It's easy to do: There is a file A1=1 A2=2 A3=3 then another file A1= Convalidation data 1,2,3 (in a dropdownlist). If I use that script in the same file, it runs, from another file not ...

Comment: I'm guessing that the range has to be in the same sheet.

Comment: You could get the values in the range as a list and then use [requireValuesInList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requireValueInList(String))

Comment: Oh yes, I have found this on internet, I have adapted and run it: var id = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('FILEID')
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheets()[0].getRange('A1:A').getValues()
  Logger.log(range)
  var projects = [];
for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
 if (range[i] != ''){
   projects.push(range[i]);
    Logger.log(projects[i]);
 } else {
   break;
  }
}
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(projects).build()     ss.getRange(i+2,2).setDataValidation(rule)

Comment: This code is not the best, but run. In this post I would like to understand why code (with requirevalueinrange) don't run. I have tried in the same sheet and it runs, but with two different files not...so I think this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

A range specified in a `Data validation` **should be in the same spreadsheet** as the range where you apply the `Data validation` to. You will notice this if you try to add it directly through the Sheets UI (when setting the range, you can only select sheets from the current spreadsheet).

#### Solution:

As was suggested in the comments, the best way to attain this behaviour is by:

- Creating an array out of the values in the source spreadsheet.
- Setting a `requireValueInList` validation rule to the destination range.

You could do something along the following lines:

```js
function dataValDifferentSS() {
  var id = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('FILEID');
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName("source").getRange("A1:A"); // Change sheet name and range accordingly
  var list = range.getValues().flat().filter(value => value !== ""); // Get 1D array from source range
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("target"); // Change sheet name accordingly
  var cell = targetSheet.getRange("A1"); // Change A1 range accordingly
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list, true).build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

#### Note:

- You should edit the source and target sheet names and ranges accordingly (`source`, `target`, `A1:A`, `A1`).
- I have assumed the script is bound to the target spreadsheet.
- You should [enable V8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime) for this script to work.

#### Reference:

- [DataValidationBuilder.requireValueInList(values, showDropdown)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinlistvalues,-showdropdown)